# How to use jQuery .css() method from pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please see my code here:

```
<div id="one">
<div class="options-parameters-input">
This is testing
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Type font size</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

var DN = document.getElementById("DN");
DN.addEventListener("keyup",both);

function both(){
document.getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0].style.fontSize = this.value+'px';
}
```

link to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/95/

but i need to use jQuery - css() method

like this:

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

but i dont know how to do that, so that i can insert value from textarea or input ? for example for font size.

My question is : how to do same thing like above code but with .css method ?

please can you write code as example ? I tried but unfortunately I have failed because I am still beginner

Thank you

Comment: It is no different.... `....css("fontSize", this.value + "px");` ....

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, or what you're trying to do. You say you don't know how to do that, yet have the line of code which does what you need...?

Comment: Do you need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5habdg/)? `.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`

Comment: If you are asking how to achieve it without jQuery, `element.style.backgroundColor='yellow'`

Comment: You can do like this, http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/96/

Comment: I was asking how to do same thing but with .css method

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy, yes something like this

Comment: This is how the question reads: "Here's how to do something using .css method - how can I do the same thing with .css method".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you want to apply the style, so I will show you how to do with jQuery, javascript or css. You choose what you need :)

jQuery:

```
var mySize = '15'
$('p').css({'background-color' : 'yellow'});
$('p').css({'font-size' : '10px'});
$('p').css({'font-size' : mySize+'px'});
```

javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); //get all p elements
element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //change background color
element.style.fontSize = "10px"; //change font-size
```

css:

```
.p {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the opposite, but not clear - ie they have some js and want the same in jquery